# Partial Sign with Unicode Math

Tags: luatex, unicode-math, libertine

I have a problem with Linux Libertine and the \partial sign.
I use following code, but there is no \partial sign (I left all my fonts there, but the problem is the font for range=\mathit):

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont[
BoldFont=LinBiolinumOB,
ItalicFont = LinBiolinumOI,
BoldItalicFont = LinLibertineOBI,
]{Linux Biolinum O}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeXGyrePagellaMath} 
\setmathfont[range=\mathup]{Linux Libertine O}
\setmathfont[range=\mathit]{Linux Libertine O Italic}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfup]{Linux Libertine O Bold}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfit]{Linux Libertine O Bold Italic}
\begin{document}
    $x\partial x$
\end{document}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a text font for math.  Try not to overwrite the math definitions by loading as follows:

```
\setmathfont[range=\mathit/{latin,Latin,num}]{Linux Libertine O Italic}
```

This will load the libertine italic font for just normal letters and numbers.  You will need to make similar adjustments to your other font loading commands.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont[
BoldFont=LinBiolinumOB,
ItalicFont = LinBiolinumOI,
BoldItalicFont = LinLibertineOBI,
]{Linux Biolinum O}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeXGyrePagellaMath} 
\setmathfont[range=\mathup]{Linux Libertine O}
\setmathfont[range=\mathit/{latin,Latin,num}]{Linux Libertine O Italic}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfup]{Linux Libertine O Bold}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfit]{Linux Libertine O Bold Italic}
\begin{document}
    $x\partial x$
\end{document}
```

Comment: If i add greek and Greek to the definition, it will also use the Libertine font for those letters